# How to compile a new PDF from GS Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I was tasked with resolving this script by an ex-co-worker, but can't figure out this error:

"Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 49 but the range has 71."

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Create Cash Proposal PDF', 'createCashProposal')
    .addToUi()
}
function createCashProposal() {
  /* 
      Author: http://haw.productions 
      Date Created: October 2019
      Updated by Amaya Maya February 2023 
  */
  let sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let pdfName = sourceSpreadsheet.getName();
  
  var sheetName1 = "B1. Cash Proposal Cover";
  var sheetName2 = "B2. Who We Are";
  var sheetName3 = "B3. Comparison";
  var sheetName4 = "B4. What We Found";
  var sheetName5 = "B5. How We Can Help";
  var sheetName6 = "B6. Project Estimate";
  var sheetName7 = "B7. Cash Flow Solution";
  var sheetName8 = "B8. Accounting Summary";
  var sheetName9 = "B9. Work Order";

  var sourceSheet1 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName1);
  var sourceSheet2 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName2);
  var sourceSheet3 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName3);
  var sourceSheet4 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName4);
  var sourceSheet5 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName5);
  var sourceSheet6 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName6);
  var sourceSheet7 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName7);
  var sourceSheet8 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName8);
  var sourceSheet9 = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName9);

  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1lzqXrqD9qUC9P2sqgnvkjQIieRylN7Yv'); 
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
 
  Logger.log("getActive: ", sourceSpreadsheet.getId());
  
  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  var destSheet1 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName1);
  var destSheet2 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName2);
  var destSheet3 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName3);
  var destSheet4 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName4);
  var destSheet5 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName5);
  var destSheet6 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName6);
  var destSheet7 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName7);
  var destSheet8 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName8);
  var destSheet9 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName9);
  
  //repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
  var sourceRange1 = sourceSheet1.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet1.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet1.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange2 = sourceSheet2.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet2.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet2.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange3 = sourceSheet3.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet3.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet3.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange4 = sourceSheet4.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet4.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet4.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange5 = sourceSheet5.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet5.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet5.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange6 = sourceSheet6.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet6.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet6.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange7 = sourceSheet7.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet7.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet7.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange8 = sourceSheet8.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet8.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet8.getMaxColumns());
  var sourceRange9 = sourceSheet9.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet9.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet9.getMaxColumns());
  
  var sourcevalues1 = sourceRange1.getValues();
  var sourcevalues2 = sourceRange2.getValues();
  var sourcevalues3 = sourceRange3.getValues();
  var sourcevalues4 = sourceRange4.getValues();
  var sourcevalues5 = sourceRange5.getValues();
  var sourcevalues6 = sourceRange6.getValues();
  var sourcevalues7 = sourceRange7.getValues();
  var sourcevalues8 = sourceRange8.getValues();
  var sourcevalues9 = sourceRange9.getValues();

  
  var destRange1 = destSheet1.getRange(1,1,destSheet1.getMaxRows(),destSheet1.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange2 = destSheet2.getRange(1,1,destSheet2.getMaxRows(),destSheet2.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange3 = destSheet3.getRange(1,1,destSheet3.getMaxRows(),destSheet3.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange4 = destSheet4.getRange(1,1,destSheet4.getMaxRows(),destSheet4.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange5 = destSheet5.getRange(1,1,destSheet5.getMaxRows(),destSheet5.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange6 = destSheet6.getRange(1,1,destSheet6.getMaxRows(),destSheet6.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange7 = destSheet7.getRange(1,1,destSheet7.getMaxRows(),destSheet7.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange8 = destSheet8.getRange(1,1,destSheet8.getMaxRows(),destSheet8.getMaxColumns());
  var destRange9 = destSheet9.getRange(1,1,destSheet9.getMaxRows(),destSheet9.getMaxColumns());
  
  destRange1.setValues(sourcevalues1);
  destRange2.setValues(sourcevalues2);
  destRange3.setValues(sourcevalues3);
  destRange4.setValues(sourcevalues4);
  destRange5.setValues(sourcevalues5);
  destRange6.setValues(sourcevalues6);
  destRange7.setValues(sourcevalues7);
  destRange8.setValues(sourcevalues8);
  destRange9.setValues(sourcevalues9);

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName1 && 
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName2 && 
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName3 && 
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName4 && 
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName5 && 
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName6 &&
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName7 &&
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName8 &&
        sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName9){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }  

  //save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<p style="font-family:arial;font-weight:bold">Click to open <a href="' + newFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + pdfName + '</a></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(80)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')  

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

The content of the presentation has changed, so I updated all the page names and combed through the rest but no luck.

//DriveApp.getRootFolder(); (<- Also not sure why this was commented out)

Comment: Where line does your error of `"Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 49 but the range has 71."` occur in your showing script?

Comment: It references line 94 before the "//delete redundant sheets" section
  
destRange8.setValues(sourcevalues8);

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `It references line 94 before the "//delete redundant sheets" section destRange8.setValues(sourcevalues8);`, your error of `"Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 49 but the range has 71."` occurs at `var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's right! Just fixed a few typos and seeing error this now 

"Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets
createCashProposal @ Code.gs:94"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your issue was changed.

Comment: From your updated question, I'm worried that your current error might depend on the Spreadsheet. Because when I tested your updated script using a simple Spreadsheet, no error occurs. And, a PDF file could be created. So, how about checking your Spreadsheet again? For example, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Would this work? [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12eqNtIhzsKb8RvUWkH-LtB63i9lwzcTi56sZI7FRX70/edit#gid=822721140)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you for this solution.
`copyTo` makes a lot of sense! 

The necessary files and folders were created by multiple users within the organization with inconsistent permissions. Your last comment helped me realize that setting up a shared admin user with the manager permissions would help clear all that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your provided sample Spreadsheet, I found the reason for your current issue. The reason for your current issue is due to the images in the cells. When the images are included in the values retrieved by `getValues`, when the values are put to the sheet using `setValues`, such an error `Service error: Spreadsheets` occurs.

In this case, as the current workaround, `copyTo` is used instead of `getValues` and `setValues`. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

First, please, rename your current function name from `createCashProposal()` to another name. And, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set `folderId`, and save the script.

```js
function createCashProposal() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.

  const sheetNames = ["B1. Cash Proposal Cover", "B2. Who We Are", "B3. Comparison", "B4. What We Found", "B5. How We Can Help", "B6. Project Estimate", "B7. Cash Flow Solution", "B8. Accounting Summary", "B9. Work Order"]; // This is from your showing script.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const dst = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder);
  const dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.open(dst);
  sheetNames.forEach(s => {
    const t1 = ss.getSheetByName(s).copyTo(ss);
    const r1 = t1.getDataRange();
    r1.copyTo(r1, { contentsOnly: true });
    const t2 = t1.copyTo(dstSS);
    t2.getDataRange().copyTo(dstSS.getSheetByName(s).getRange("A1"), { contentsOnly: true });
    ss.deleteSheet(t1);
    dstSS.deleteSheet(t2);
  });
  const sheets = dstSS.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
      dstSS.deleteSheet(s);
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const pdfName = ss.getName();
  const blob = dstSS.getBlob().setName(pdfName);
  const newFile = folder.createFile(blob);
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p style="font-family:arial;font-weight:bold">Click to open <a href="' + newFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + pdfName + '</a></p>').setWidth(300).setHeight(80);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful');
  DriveApp.getFileById(dstSS.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

- When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. A PDF file could be created.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful abuot this.